# Does Nexus 5 support EAP SIM authentication?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, nexus-5, stock-android, wifi-hotspot

As the title says, I can't seem to get it working at all. I am running Android 5.0.1 on Nexus 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the answer on SO by chihchun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21289778/2821954),

> **Since the AOSP did not have EAP-SIM support**, there are different implementations on the market. [...]

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Also, looking at the list of supported devices for EAP-SIM on [this site](http://www.ida.gov.sg/Infocomm-Landscape/Infrastructure/Wireless/Wireless-at-SG/For-Consumer/List-of-Supported-Devices), I didn't see any Google Nexus products, which might prove the statement on that answer.

<sup>Note: I would say that the list might be too localized and not too updated, so don't take it as a hard fact. Also, the answer was posted on Jan '14 (before Lollipop), so it might be outdated.</sup>

OTOH, it seems that Nexus 6 actually has this function, and Nexus 5 *was supposed to also have* it. However, [Issue #81587 on AOSP Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81587) and [Issue #509 on Lollipop developer preview](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=509) might tell that Nexus 5 doesn't support EAP-SIM, even on 5.0.1 Lollipop.

Comment: is it possible to do manual login by extracting EAP-SIM info?